# Unable to read TensorFlow trained model into OpenCV 3.4.1

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I am trying to read the TensorFlow trained model in OpenCV, I have downloaded ssd_inception_v2_coco and ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) model while reading the Net like this:

```
String basePath = "/home/adil/Desktop/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/";
String model = basePath + "frozen_inference_graph.pb";
Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(model);
```

But it throws this error:

> tf_importer.cpp:1582: error: (-2) Unknown layer type Cast in op
>   ToFloat in function populateNet

Why it should throw the error, is there anything else to configure? If yes, then how can be done to successfully read and use the TF trained model into OpenCV application.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you not mandatory need tf implementation of mobilenet, there is ready to use implementation in opencv's samples. See samples/dnn/ssd_mobilenet_object_detection.cpp there you can find caffe based implementation. Tensorflow ops are not fully supported by opencv now.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know that, but I want to train my own model and use it in OpenCV, Or I want to use some other models of the TF, not only mobile-net. But I think OpenCV doesn't support ditectly use TF models, am I right?

Comment: I supports use of frozen TF models as they are, but many ops are not supported yet, so networks must be designed specially to be used with opencv later.

Comment: So there is no way TF models get to run with OpenCV? If it is like this, then the DNN module cannot be used with TF. :(

Comment: In short, yes, you can't load any model designed in TF in opencv, only specially designed using ops that implemented on opencv's dnn module can be run directly.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the explanation, I got the answer.